# The len() of this list is not coming out right: Python

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to count the number of times the word "fizz" appears in my list. This is the code:

```
def fizz_count(key):
    for x in key:

        if x != 'fizz':
            key.remove(x)
            return len(key)

print fizz_count(["fizz",0,0,0,10])
```

However, this returns 4 instead of 1. Any help with my code?

Comment: Just use the built-in `count` method: `["fizz",0,0,0,10].count("fizz")`.

Comment: @BrenBarn Wait wait, i'm removing all the items which aren't "fizz". Aren't i?

Comment: No, you're not, as the answers explain.  You remove one item and then your function ends.

Comment: Beside all other problems, you might be surprised what happens to your list `l` if you do `l = [whatever it contains]; fizz_count(l); print l`: it destroys it. So the `.count()` stuff is more preferable.

Answer (score 6):

As soon as a function returns something, it breaks. Hence, when you do `return len(key)`, you return the length of the list after removing the first `0`.

If you want to count how many times something appears in a list, just do `key.count('fizz')`

---

You should never remove items from a list while iterating over it. Look what would happen if you continued your loop, and there were more `"fizz"`es:

```
>>> key = ['fizz', 1, 2, 3, 'fizz', 4]
>>> for x in key:
...     if x != 'fizz':
...             key.remove(x)
...             print key # Print the list after an item is removed.
... 
['fizz', 2, 3, 'fizz', 4]
['fizz', 2, 'fizz', 4]
['fizz', 2, 'fizz']
```

Notice how it never removed the `2`? Because the for-loop never got up to it, because the list's length/order changed.

Answer (score 2):

First off all you should be using the standard library's count method to do the same:

```
["fizz",0,0,0,10].count("fizz")
```

It should return 1. However, if you would like to go with your own logic, then here is the updated one:

```
def fizz_count(key):
    for x in key:
        if x != 'fizz':
            key.remove(x)
    return len(key)

print fizz_count(["fizz",0,0,0,10])
```

The return statement inside the if block causes the function to return as quick as you find the first element not matching the "fizz". So, Since you have a list of 5 elements, you will always be getting 4 as an output.

Answer (score 1):

It returns `4` instead of `1` because the indentation causes the `return` to be a part of the `if` condition.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably write this function via generator expression, like so:

```
def fizz_count(key):
    return len([x for x in key if x == 'fizz'])
```

That way you won't get into issues which occur when you iterate over the collection and remove its elements at the same time. Or, as some other users pointed out, I'd use `count` function (though I didn't know about it before - thanks to everyone who've shown it in this thread).

P.S. In my opinion generator expressions are more higher level constructions and should be used instead of loops (yeah, I know there're some cases when the loop construction will give you clearer code - you should always think what will be the best way to write it).

Comment: Still returns ['fizz',0,10]. The problem is, he shouldn't modify a list while it's being iterated.

Comment: @alKamili, you're absolutely right. I've completely forgot about the issues which occur when we iterate over the collection and remove its elements at the same time. I'll remove the "fixed" version of code. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: You have a *list* comprehension, not a *generator* expression